# SwiftyJSON not reloading the UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, swifty-json

I'm working on a project right now and I'm using SwiftyJSON to parse the json from my server, at first it loads great, but when i reload it, it doesn't seem to work until i restart the app, here's the method that i used:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        connectToServer()
        self.refreshControls.addTarget(self, action: "connectToServer", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
        self.tableView.addSubview(self.refreshControls)
    }

    func connectToServer() {
        let urlString = "http://myserver.com/"

        if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
            if let data = try? NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: []) {

                let json = JSON(data: data)
                self.parseJSON(json)

            }
        }


    }


    func parseJSON(json: JSON) {
        numberOfRows = json.count
        for i in 0...numberOfRows {


            let name = json[i]["name"].stringValue
            let age = json[i]["age"].stringValue
            let g = json[i]["gender"].stringValue
            let b = json[i]["bday"].stringValue


            names.append(name)
            ages.append(age)
            genders.append(g)
            bdays.append(b)
        }


        tableView.reloadData()
        self.refreshControls.endRefreshing()

    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return numberOfRows
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! MainCell!
        if cell == nil {
            cell = MainCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        }

            cell.nameLbl.text = names[indexPath.row]
            cell.ageLbl.text = ages[indexPath.row]
            cell.genderLbl.text = genders[indexPath.row]
            cell.bdayLbl.text = bdays[indexPath.row]



        return cell
    }
```

Did I missed something? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share the class definition and the decalaration of variables (tableView, etc.) too. 
Also, if the tableView.reloadData() being called?

Comment: Have you checked that you hit `tableView.reladData()` and is `numberOfRows` updated? OT you should make a model and make an object instead of having four different arrays.

Comment: where did you clear data array like names, ages...? You just appended it, and numberOfRows got replaced by Json.count, So new added data may not appear

Comment: **Do not** use 4 different arrays for each parameter. Use a custom class with 4 properties for the parameters and **one** array for the instances, then return `array.count` in `numberOfRowsInSection`. Furthermore you have to remove all entries before adding new ones.

Comment: numberOfRows variable is an Int, i just used it to declare it to `numberOfRowsInSection`. tableView.reloadData() is being called when pulling down the tableView using `UIRefreshControl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggestion for a better workflow.

Create a custom class

```
class Person {

  let name : String
  let age : String
  let gender : String
  let birthday : String

  init(name: String, age : String, gender: String, birthday : String)
  {
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.gender = gender
    self.birthday = birthday
  }
}
```

In your view controller declare a variable `people`

```
var people = [Person]()
```

Change `parseJSON` to this code for creating `Person` instances

```
func parseJSON(json: JSON) {
  people.removeAll()
  for i in 0..<json.count {
    let item = json[i]
    let person = Person(name: item["name"].stringValue,
      age: item["age"].stringValue,
      gender: item["gender"].stringValue,
      birthday: item["bday"].stringValue)
    people.append(person)
  }

  tableView.reloadData()
  self.refreshControls.endRefreshing()
}
```

Then return the number of persons in `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return people.count
}
```

and update the UI with

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! MainCell
  if cell == nil {
    cell = MainCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
  }
  let person = people[indexPath.row]
  cell.nameLbl.text = person.name
  cell.ageLbl.text = person.age
  cell.genderLbl.text = person.gender
  cell.bdayLbl.text = person.birthday
  return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. I just cleared all entities as vadian says. Like this:

```
func connectToServer() {

        names.removeAll()
        ages.removeAll()
        genders.removeAll()
        bdays.removeAll()

        let urlString = "http://myserver.com/"

        if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
            if let data = try? NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: []) {

                let json = JSON(data: data)
                self.parseJSON(json)

            }
        }


    }
```

Thanks for all you comments!